# Gitlab webhook get error: 500 Internal Server Error - URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-ci

With Gitlab *(10.6.2)* and Jenkins installed on local machine, and trying to auto build via gitlab's webhook, according to https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example

But, when test push, gitlab get error:

> 500 Internal Server Error - URI::InvalidURIError

The detailed log in `production.log` is:

> Started GET "/laiwan/laiwan-parent/hooks/2/test?trigger=push_events"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-03 17:11:07 +0800 Processing by
>   Projects::HooksController#test as HTML    Parameters:
>   {"trigger"=>"push_events", "namespace_id"=>"laiwan",
>   "project_id"=>"laiwan-parent", "id"=>"2"} Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
>
> URI::InvalidURIError (URI::InvalidURIError):
>   lib/gitlab/proxy_http_connection_adapter.rb:14:in `connection'
>
>   app/services/web_hook_service.rb:73:in`make_request'
>   app/services/web_hook_service.rb:26:in `execute'
>
>   app/models/hooks/web_hook.rb:10:in`execute'
>   app/services/test_hooks/base_service.rb:22:in `block in execute'
>
>   app/services/test_hooks/base_service.rb:19:in`catch'
>   app/services/test_hooks/base_service.rb:19:in `execute'
>
>   app/controllers/projects/hooks_controller.rb:41:in`test'
>   lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:50:in `with_locale'   lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:56:in`
>   with_user_locale'   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:330:in
>   `set_locale'   lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:95:in`call'
>   lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
>
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in`call'
>   lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:in `call'
>
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:28:in`call'
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:16:in `call'
>
>   lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in`call'
>   lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
>
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:10:in`call'

Gitlab webhook's url is `http://localhost:8282/project/laiwan-parent`, it's valid.

Seems someone asked similar issue on gitlab's issues page, but didn't get any respond yet: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/5375

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3307

**The reason is:**

In new version of gitlab, by default it doesn't allow request to local network via webhook.

**Solution:**

- Login to gitlab as root.
- Click `Admin area` icon on top -> Settings.
- In section `Outbound requests`, check `Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services`, and save.

Then the webhook request could be sent to jenkins on the same host successfully.

*(BTW, though gitlab is an excellent tool, but this option should definitely be checked by default I think, or at least pop out some clear tip about what's going on, instead of the 500 error, to save develop's time on fix such issues.)*

Comment: This is a slightly different issue, but when I do the above and click "save", I get a 500 error page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the setting [Outbound requests] when I login as admin account to GitLab CE. Is it located some where else in version 10.7.3

Comment: I discovered I have to use the admin account to access that setting. So I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

In gitlab 11.x the option has been moved to **/admin/application_settings/network**  The documentation is not up-to-date